# Send and Take Over string or int from View to View in querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to send and take over a variable (int or string) 
From(for example) **/Home/Index** to **/Home/Index/Site(here will be transmitted variables)** and from there to other next View this same variable in simple way?

I need to send (for example) **OwnerID** (from **Home/Index** to the next Action) where i have to show only owner's table elements. I can go from here to the category **(Home/CategoryOne)** where i have to show only Owner's elements and only from this category. So I have to somehow take **OwnerID** from first step and **CategoryName** from second step to sho Owner's **CategoryOne** elements. In the next step, I need to add the ability to edit these data...

Comment: Have you looked at adding a custom route for this?

Comment: Your question suggests that you want to send the data initially to the Index action on your Home controller and then redirect to a different controller/action. Is there a reason that you need to do that specifically, or could you send the user directly to the controller/action that you want from the /Home/Index view? I.e. render a link (or <form> if that's what you want) that points to the destination controller/action via the ActionLink (or BeginForm) method?

Comment: I need to send (for example) OwnerID (from Home/Index to the next Action) where i have to show only owner's table elements. I can go from here to the category (Home/CategoryOne) where i have to show only Owner's elements and only from this category. So I have to somehow take OwnerID from first step and CategoryName from second step to sho Owner's CategoryOne elements. In the next step, I need to add the ability to edit these data...

Comment: @voltdev that information's helpful to better understand what you need. If you edit your question to provide that additional detail; you'll be more likely to get answers. The question is pretty sparse as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use RedirectToAction in MVC https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx For example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var myTestId = 0;
    return RedirectToAction("Site", new { myId = myTestId });
}

public ActionResult Site(int myId)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Foo", new { testId = myId });
}
```